# URL Rewrite by .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 3 urls and i want to rewrite :

```
`health.php?news=apple` to `/health/news/apple`
```

`health.php?info=apple` to `/health/info/apple` 
`health.php?articles=apple` to `/health/articles/apple`

for this i write below given code :

```
RewriteRule ^health health.php
RewriteRule health/news/(.*) /health.php?news=$1 [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule health/info/(.*) /health.php?info=$1 [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule health/articles/(.*) /health.php?articles=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

But this isn't working .
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first rule will redirect anything that starts with health, your 3 other rules would never match because RewriteRule does not start with a slash.

Comment: sorry but this was my written mistake...

Comment: Do you want to redirect when you access the PHP page or when you access the pretty URL? do you have multiple .htaccess? what is your folder structure?

Comment: I have wordpress site. In root directory i created htaccess file and create health.php. Basically health.php is my search page of my website.
Its created 3 links for 3 titles : 
http://localhost/health.php?news=apple
http://localhost/health.php?info=apple
http://localhost/health.php?articles=apple
and i want to open and works url like : 
http://localhost/health/articles/apple
http://localhost/health/info/apple
http://localhost/health/news/apple

Comment: @RahulGupta if you are using wordpress why don't you try using the wordpress permalink?

Comment: Yes, that would be the best way if you're using wordpress

Comment: @harikrish health.php is my costume page not wp page.

Comment: @RahulGupta if you want to conver that page into something that wordpress can handle, see this url http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^health/(.*)/(.*) health.php?$1=$2
```

The above code will redirect to health page and then use the first variable as the get variable key and the second one as the value.

Comment: Hi Harikrish thanks for comment after putting this code to .htaccess file page going on page404. :(

Comment: @RahulGupta health spelling was not correct, i had corrected it , can you try now

Comment: it work now with following code : 

RewriteRule ^health/(.*)/(.*) health.php?$1=$2 
RewriteRule ^health health.php

Comment: Hi Harikrish....Help me again....
how can i redirect:

(http://localhost/health/apple) to (http://localhost/health/search/apple)

Comment: RewriteRule ^health/search/(.*)/(.*) health.php?$1=$2

Comment: my some page index in google with www.abc.com/health/apple and i want to open this page like www.abc.com/health/search/apple.

Comment: okay if  www.abc.com/health/apple comes it will be redirect to www.abc.com/health/search/apple using the below code. RewriteRule ^health/(.*) health/search/$1